# why dont apache kafka use the standard java doc?

Tags: apache-kafka

```
public class CommonClientConfigs {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommonClientConfigs.class);

    /*
     * NOTE: DO NOT CHANGE EITHER CONFIG NAMES AS THESE ARE PART OF THE PUBLIC API AND CHANGE WILL BREAK USER CODE.
     */

    public static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG = "bootstrap.servers";
    public static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_DOC = "A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster. The client will make use of all servers irrespective of which servers are specified here for bootstrapping&mdash;this list only impacts the initial hosts used to discover the full set of servers. This list should be in the form "
                                                       + "<code>host1:port1,host2:port2,...</code>. Since these servers are just used for the initial connection to "
                                                       + "discover the full cluster membership (which may change dynamically), this list need not contain the full set of "
                                                       + "servers (you may want more than one, though, in case a server is down).";

    public static final String CLIENT_DNS_LOOKUP_CONFIG = "client.dns.lookup";
    public static final String CLIENT_DNS_LOOKUP_DOC = "Controls how the client uses DNS lookups. If set to <code>use_all_dns_ips</code> then, when the lookup returns multiple IP addresses for a hostname,"
                                                       + " they will all be attempted to connect to before failing the connection. Applies to both bootstrap and advertised servers."
                                                       + " If the value is <code>resolve_canonical_bootstrap_servers_only</code> each entry will be resolved and expanded into a list of canonical names.";

}
```

I just dont understand why they dont use the standard javadoc to comment.
anyone has idea about this?